# ¿Cómo leer archivos html con php (con todo y etiquetas)?

Tags: php, html

Estoy usando `file_get_content("ruta.html");`

Si el archivo `ruta.html` contiene `<p>Hola</p> entre (entre etiquetas "<"p">")`

El archivo php escribe:

```
hola
```

Pero yo necesito que escriba:

```
"<p>Hola</p>"
```

con todo y etiquetas "<>"

Comment: Quieres abrir el archivo para ver y modificar el contenido? `echo '<textarea id="arriba" name="arriba" cols="60" rows="10">'.file_get_contents('r.txt').'</textarea>';`

Answer (score 2):

Basta con que uses [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php) para codificar los caractéres especiales a una  entidad html.

```
<?php
    echo htmlentities(file_get_content("ruta.html"), ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
```

Un ejemplo

```
[eduen@EDUENPC ~]$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo htmlentities('<p>Hola </p>', ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
&lt;p&gt;Hola &lt;&sol;p&gt;
php > echo htmlentities('<p>Hola </p>', ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
&lt;p&gt;Hola &lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: La respuesta de Eduen esta bien pero puede que no os funcione por que es file_get_contents con s y no sin la s como ha puesto.